# Is my employer allowed to make me work without pay?

Tags: united-states, employment, labor-law, workplace, georgia

As the title says: A coworker and I had recently made a mistake at work. In response to this, our manager decides we have to work for two extra hours on our next shifts unpaid. Is this legal?
I work in the State of Georgia in the US, by the way.

Comment: Are you a salaried worker?  Are you a "manager" in title?  Is your salary significantly above minimum wage?  (these can all matter both legally and practically)

Comment: How did they phrase this?  Did they say, "We are docking your pay the amount of the loss," and this has the *effect* of making two hours of your work free, or did they explicitly say "We want you to work two hours for free"?

Comment: Full-time Engineering workers are "exempt" from overtime pay requirements under US law (although sometimes employers will throw them a little something to encourage extra work). And of course engineers are rather overrepresented in the userbase of StackExchange sites, due to the technical sites. So this is really a crucial missing piece of information from this question at the moment.

Comment: @T.E.D. Full-time Engineering workers are not exempt unless they are true managers or they are salaried AND make above the field-specific minimum. (E.g., in California, for computer software employees, it's $112,065.20 annually.) Georgia seems to follow the lower federal standard of the FLSA, however, and the employee must be salaried and earn a minimum of $35,568.

Comment: @David - There are a lot of nitty technical rules for what allows an employer to classify an employee as exempt. What you gave is also an simplification, but I suppose I was being naïve in posting my own simplification and hoping I wouldn't touch off a "well actually..." war. Suffice to say my comment was not intended as a complete specification of the law, yours isn't either, and doing so here in the comments would be off-topic. The OP probably knows the answer, but if they don't their HR department certainly can tell them. We need that updated into the question in order to be able to answer.

Comment: what does your union say?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This is illegal, under the Fair Labor Standards Act, assuming you are not an "exempt" employee, which is primarily a salaried employee (your pay isn't based on how many hours you work). There are details about the complaint process [here](https://www.dol.gov/agencies/whd/contact/complaints). It is useful to know that retaliation against an employee filing a legal complaint is also illegal.

Comment: The retaliation might be illegal, but the work climate definitely won't improve if you complain.

Comment: It might be worthwhile to mention that if the "extra hours" bring the total hours for the week above 40 then the employee must be paid at least 1.5 times the regular rate of pay.  But would the employer be able to reduce the regular rate of pay temporarily?  For example, if the employee makes $10 an hour, normally earning $400 for a 40-hour work week, couldn't the employer reduce the wage to $9.30 and require two hours of overtime at $13.95?  For two extra hours, the reduced wage would be above the $7.25 minimum if the current wage is at least $8.07.

Comment: @phoog That ends up in the question whether the employer can make an employee pay for an error he makes. And I'm pretty sure the answer is also No.

Comment: @phoog that'd depend on the contract. Mine for example states both the number of hours it covers AND the amount being paid per hour. That contract is legally binding. If it only states the number of hours being worked and not the amount being paid out, the employer can pay whatever the heck they want per hour as long as it's not below the legal minimum wage and they're good. But I've never seen such a contract, and wouldn't sign it if I did see it

Comment: @jwenting I suppose you've never been employed in the US.  in Georgia, like every US jurisdiction other than Montana, employment is "at will" by default, and exceptions to this default are rare outside of unionized jobs.  Either party can terminate the terms of employment at any time for any reason (apart from certain statutory prohibitions such as certain forms of discrimination) or for no reason.  If the employee signed a contract, which is unlikely, there is likely a clause covering changes in the wage that allows it to be lowered as well as raised.

Comment: @jwenting see https://www.ncsl.org/labor-and-employment/at-will-employment-overview "the U.S. at-will rule leaves employees vulnerable to arbitrary and sudden dismissal, a limited or on-call work schedule depending on the employer’s needs, and unannounced cuts in pay and benefits."

Comment: @PMF the answer is no in some US states, not including Georgia, if [this article from Avvo is correct](https://www.avvo.com/legal-library/employment-law/paycheck-deductions-for-employee-mistakes-federal-and-state-pay-docking-laws.html).  Reductions in pay are allowed as long as the pay remains above minimum wage.

Comment: @phoog Thanks for that link. I guess _if_ I ever work in the US, I'd have to carefuly consider the state...

Comment: Retroactive reductions in pay are not.  But I suspect that if your salary is above min wage, they could reduce it to min wage until the extra time you work "off the clock" is "paid off", then bump it back up again.  Not doing this will run into federal law problems.

Comment: The main question of legality is whether this is retribution for complaining about the pay suspension.

Comment: @phoog Why would it be unlikely for an employee to sign a contract? I know that employment in the US is generally at-will, but I was under the impression that most jobs do at least come with contracts…

Comment: Retaliation is illegal, but most managers are smart enough to manufacture a legal excuse for whatever action they take.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet in my experience there is a document purporting not to be a contract that outlines various terms of the employee's employment.  If the letter is taken at face value, or in the absence of any signed document (which can also happen, again in my experience), then the contract of employment is verbal, and the employee hasn't signed a contract.

Comment: I don't see anything in the FLSA or Georgia law that would make this illegal. Presumably, the OP is paid hourly and presumably their pay would still be above minimum wage for the number of hours worked in the pay period. While many states do make this illegal, Georgia isn't one of them.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet most jobs do not come with well-codified contracts. If you have a contract, you are very often a contractor, not an employee, and many of the legal protections for employees are less applicable.

Comment: @fectin So most US employees have nothing that confirms their employment? That seems quite bizarre to a (north) European mind. Even the paper route I had when I was about 13 or 14 required me signing a contract. Legal protections for employees that can’t even prove they’re employees sounds like a… less than reliable concept.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: A written contract isn't the only way to prove you're an employee.  In case of a legal dispute, you'd have your own testimony, the compelled testimony of the employer, the testimony of any co-workers, etc., to show that you were in fact working for the employer.  If you need written evidence to show to a third party, pay stubs are typically used.  But yeah, it's very different from the European model.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Most US employees will have a contract or employment agreement, but one that does not specify a specific term (duration) of employment.  The agreement can and will explicitly say the employment is "at-will" and that the contract does not impart any rights to future continuing employment.

Answer (score 0):

Per the article "[Overtime Rules for Exempt and Non-Exempt Employees](https://www.thebalancemoney.com/exempt-vs-non-exempt-employees-overtime-rules-397359)":

> The Department of Labor (DOL) has rules for when employers must pay overtime to employees. The DOL assumes every worker must receive overtime pay if they work over 40 hours in a week, at a rate equal to 1.5 times their hourly rate (at a minimum).1 But some employees, because of the nature of their work, are considered to be "exempt" from overtime pay.
>
> It used to be that the terms "exempt" and "non-exempt" were clearly defined. But the DOL has more rules to protect lower-paid exempt employees from falling below the minimum wage, by requiring that they must be paid overtime."